# Separate domain from corporate domain space and Kubernetes domain space?

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I'm building on-prem kubernetes cluster and we are a windows shop.  If we have AD.com as our corporate AD DNS Server, should we use the same namespace for the kubernetes cluster?

My "hunch" is that I should create a separate domain for the cluster and then setup domain forwarding.

Ex.

- AD.com --> Setup conditional forwarding to Cluster.local
- Cluster.local --> use default to inherit from host, or setup stub
  lookup

Any best practices advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set them up separately. Setting up `cluster.local` in AD will probably lead to unpredictable results.

`cluster.local` is a domain for Kubernetes to resolve names 'internally' in a cluster.

Hope it helps!